# Telerik DatePicker id conflict with partial views

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm working on a project that uses the Telerik DatePicker.  The app switches through partial views that share the same field name.  DatePicker requires the name specified by `Name()` to be the name of the field in the data model.  (As far as I can tell the call to .Value(Model.DataField) is redundant.)

```
@(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
    .Name("DataField")
    .ShowButton(true)
    .Value(Model.DataField))
```

What happens is that the control is created with the id of DataField.  So with two partials for the same field name there are two identical ids.  One works (the first one shown) and the other is dead.

I've tried adding `.HtmlAttributes(new { id="DataField_wrapper" })` to the lineup but it doesn't change the problematic id.  This id shows up in a dev that wraps the control:

```
<div class="t-widget t-datepicker" id="DataField_wrapper">
    <div class="t-picker-wrap">
        <input class="t-input" .... id="DataField" name="DataField" type="text">
```

Using jQuery to grab the elements via `#DataField`, one will have a `.data("tDatePicker")` and the other will not.

Is there a decent way to get both of these controls working?

Comment: Why do you need to have the same DatePicker in 2 Partial Views ? Can't you change your model to have 2 date properties for this case ?

Comment: The page is pulling from two different models, each with a StartDate field (for example).  Each is shown by its own partial but not at the same time; and then there is also a popup partial for creating a new record, and it will also display a StartDate.  I've played with renaming fields uniquely in the models, and could go this brute-force route if that is the only solution.  Just seems there should be a better way to wrap it somehow.

Comment: If you change the name, does it affect the name of the <input> tag or just it's id? I'm wondering if the <input name> attribute is controlled by the value field.

Have you tried DatePickerFor as an alternative?

Comment: @B2K name and id are always the same.  Calling the Name("newname") method sets both id and name. But if this value doesn't match the field name in the model, then it won't update.  Same story for DatePickerFor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `HtmlAttributes` to set the `id` sets the value for a wrapper div.  `InputHtmlAttributes` is what is needed!  This affects the actual input control so that a unique `id` can be assigned.

```
@(Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(x => Model.DataField)
    .InputHtmlAttributes(new {id="UniqueID"}))
```

This yields:

```
<div class="t-widget t-datepicker">
    <div class="t-picker-wrap">
        <input class="t-input" .... id="UniqueID" name="DataField" type="text">
```

and works as desired.